# Django collectstatic command not finding and copying static files

Tags: django

I'm setting up my static files for Django to collect with this setup,

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = "127.0.0.1:8000/static/"
```

I made a static folder inside my app

```
 my_app/static/my_app/my_css_framework_directory
```

My my_css_framework_directory contains the following directories, css, img, and js.

But when I ran python manage.py collectstatic, 0 files are copied?

Comment: STATIC_ROOT should just be `'/static/'` I think. Or try setting it to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')` where `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` this is what i do. This will set it relative to your settings.py file.

Comment: @elethan my BASE_DIR is already set, docu says web path should work.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I am not sure then. I have never tried it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT` should be the absolute path to your static directory https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: STATIC_ROOT worked but can not find static files in my_app/static/my_app/my_css_framework_directory?

Comment: @anna-vracheva is right, the `STATIC_ROOT` must point to a filesystem location.

Comment: @rafalmp yes anna is correct about STATIC_ROOT just wondering why collectstatic command can not find my static files for collection? I did what docu said "Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example my_app/static/my_app/myimage.jpg."?

Comment: In  your question you wrote that it is set as follows: `STATIC_ROOT = "127.0.0.1:8000/static/"` so we don't know which version is current. If you changed your setting, please edit your question accordingly.